# Crashes the app when i'm displaying data from the database

Tags: php, android

when I press the button "btUpdPlata" That is placed in the Activity `MainActivity` and shows the data of the column "Plata" (numerical value in the database) of the respective user after login stops working the app

I did several tests, but it always ends up crashing the app, What can be?

plata.php

```
<?php
include_once("conn.php");

$plata=$_GET['plata'];
$query="SELECT * FROM signup where plata='{$plata}'";


$result=mysqli_query($conn ,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$output_info = "Plata ".$row['plata'];


echo "platita";
echo $output_info;


}
mysqli_close();


?>
```

Background plata

```
public class BackgroundWorkerPlata extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
MainActivity ob;
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorkerPlata (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "insert url here";
    if(type.equals("plata")) {
        try {
            String plata = params[5];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("plata","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(plata,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Cargando dinero");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    // alertDialog.show();
    if (result.contentEquals("platita")) {
        ob.PlataET.setText(result.toString().replace(',','\n'));


    }
}



@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate (Void...values){
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

In MainActivity:

```
public void cambiarTextoUpdatePlata(View v) {
    String plata = PlataET.getText().toString();
    String type = "plata";
    BackgroundWorkerPlata backgroundWorkerPlata = new BackgroundWorkerPlata(this);
    backgroundWorkerPlata.execute(type, plata);

    TextView updatePlata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlataET);
    updatePlata.setText("Tienes " + plata + " Pesos");
    {
    }
```

Button:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btUpdPlata"
    android:onClick="cambiarTextoUpdatePlata"
    android:text="Actualizar Plata" />
```

UPDATE

crash:

```
08-06 03:11:05.690 23352-23352/net.prontocars.prontocars E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: net.prontocars.prontocars, PID: 23352
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at net.prontocars.prontocars.MainActivity.cambiarTextoUpdatePlata(MainActivity.java:45)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

UPDATE 2

new crash after fix textview

```
08-06 05:03:31.719 12631-12631/net.prontocars.prontocars E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: net.prontocars.prontocars, PID: 12631
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at net.prontocars.prontocars.BackgroundWorkerPlata.onPostExecute(BackgroundWorkerPlata.java:99)
                                                                           at net.prontocars.prontocars.BackgroundWorkerPlata.onPostExecute(BackgroundWorkerPlata.java:43)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Share your error log stack trace also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in your code, You used `PlataET` at first line and its giving NullPointerException, and we can see you created that object after couple of lines, So create and then use that.

Try like this,

```
public void cambiarTextoUpdatePlata(View v) {
    PlataET = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlataET);
    String plata = PlataET.getText().toString();
    String type = "plata";
    BackgroundWorkerPlata backgroundWorkerPlata = new BackgroundWorkerPlata(this);
    backgroundWorkerPlata.execute(type, plata);


    PlataET.setText("Tienes " + plata + " Pesos");
```

Edited for Error 2:
You are checking the string with null object, So change the condition like this,

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(result) && result.contentEquals("platita")) {
   ob.PlataET.setText(result.toString().replace(',','\n'));
}
```

Comment: appears "Tiene" and "Pesos" but the value of "plata" does not appear and crashes

Comment: Check your crash log again, Are you getting same error.?

Comment: post edited with new crash, EDIT: i edit the update 2 crash

Comment: still dont appears the value of "plata" but now not crashes

Comment: In your PHP you are using **GET* $phone=$_GET['plata'], but in Android, you are sending in POST, I am not sure it will work or not in PHP.

Comment: still dont works :/ i replace $phone=$_GET['plata'] to $plata=$_POST['plata'] but does not appears the value

Comment: Try to put the same URL in browser and check.

Comment: appears `Notice: Undefined index: plata in /storage/ssd5/872/2360872/public_html/UserRegistration/plata.php on line 4
platitaPlata 0platitaPlata 0platitaPlata 0platitaPlata 0                                                     

   |||  Warning: mysqli_close() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /storage/ssd5/872/2360872/public_html/UserRegistration/plata.php on line 19`